# OAuth : Después de haber sido autenticado, utilizar el access token

Tags: nodejs, express, passport

estoy tratando de aprender el flujo del OAuth, pero me pierdo un poco en cómo realizar requests después de haber sido autenticado. Es decir, en mi código después de haber iniciado sesión (en este caso utilizando la API de spotify), quisiera obtener las playlist del usuario que inició sesión, pero necesito el acces token, que entiendo que ya lo he generado al autenticarme. Ahora, ¿cómo recupero ese access token para usarlo? ¿o debería obtenerlo nuevamente?

Hablando concretamente del código, al autenticarme con *passport js*, el access token se genera ok. Luego, al querer usarlo en '/user', ¿cómo debería obtenerlo?

```
const ensureAuth = (req,res,next)=>{
  if(req.isAuthenticated()) return next();
  res.redirect('/');
}

dotenv.config();

const Strategy = new SpotifyStrategy({
  clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
  callbackURL: 'http://localhost:8888/auth/spotify/callback'
},
function(accessToken, refreshToken, expires_in, profile, done) {
  // Aqui el access token lo tengo ! 
  process.nextTick(function(){
    return done(null, profile);
  })
})

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done){
  done(null, user);
});

passport.use(Strategy);

const app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname,'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(cookieParser());

// config express-session
const sess = {
  secret: 'my little secret',
  cookie: {},
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
};

app.use(session(sess));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

const stateKey = 'spotify_auth_state';

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
  res.render('index', {user: req.user});
})

app.get('/user', ensureAuth, async (req,res, next) => {
  let playlists_url = `https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/${req.user.id}/playlists`;
  // Acá no tengo al access token :( 
  res.render('user', {
    user : req.user
  })
})

app.get('/auth/spotify', passport.authenticate('spotify', {
  scope: ['user-read-email', 'user-read-private', 'playlist-read-private', 'playlist-read-collaborative'],
  showDialog : false
}), (req, res) => {})

app.get(
  '/auth/spotify/callback',
  passport.authenticate('spotify', {failureRedirect: '/index'}),
  (req,res) => {res.redirect('/user')}
)
```

Comment: estas utilizando backend y frontend por separado ?

Comment: Pensaba hacerlo. Pero por el momento solo estoy programando el backend

Comment: si estas utilizando express-session no veo por que la necesidad de utilizar tokens, lo que deberias hacer es serializar y deserializar bien los datos, algo que no estas haciendo bien

Comment: ¿Cómo sería eso?